# Show time label in Interface Controller presented modally

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

By default, Interface Controllers presented modally have only the "Cancel" button in the status bar. Is it possible to show the time label also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to control the display of the time label. You can only customize the text displayed. For example, you could change "Cancel" to "Done" by setting the title of the `WKInterfaceController` in the storyboard or in code. Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1) to more info provided by Apple in the programming guide.